# (Reopened) What's the justification for closing the question around a scheme to optimize remuneration?

Tags: discussion, reopen-request

[How to convince my hierarchy to optimize my remuneration scheme](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/181750/how-to-convince-my-hierarchy-to-optimize-my-remuneration-scheme)

It was closed with the reason:

> Questions seeking advice on company-specific regulations, agreements, or policies should be directed to your manager or HR department.

This question IS NOT asking "advice  on company-specific regulations, agreements, or policies", it's asking for strategies on how to influence these things.

This isn't a nuanced thing. It's pretty obvious the intention behind this close reason is not realised here.

It has been suggested that questions should be voted to close if you can't think of a good answer. I disagree with this rationale, but below in an example answer for the proposed question that shows the question is answerable without knowing specifics around the organisation in question, and thus is generally applicable to others:

> Whenever there is organisational change, you have to broadly answer
> two questions:
>
> What is the benefit/risk for the business? What is the benefit for
> others that are to instigate the change?
>
> In both cases, there is associated risk involved. You have to look at
> it from the perspective of the HR person:
>
> - Will this change be easy to implement?
> - Do we understand the legal issues around this change?
> - Will it benefit the company in some sort of meaningful way?
> - If this goes south for some reason, will I get fired?
> - Is there a reason we are not doing this already?
> - Is this a good use of my time?
> - Is the employee worth satisfying?
> - Will other affected employees agree with this change?
>
> So, to instigate the change you want, you have to think of reasons
> that cover the above questions, and also recognise that you may not
> have great answers to the above questions.
>
> If your boss is not willing to engage with HR, they probably do not
> think that HR can be convinced.
>
> In any case, in the future, you should look carefully over any
> employment contracts, and not make any assumptions about renumeration.

Comment: I think it's not a great reason to close it, but the question seems unanswerable. It's a specific scheme and a company and the normal recourses have already been denied. Do you have a useful answer to post?

Comment: @Kilisi I don't know if me having an answer is a good metric to determine if a question should be closed.

Comment: @Kilisi In any case, I don't think questions should be closed if you or I have reached the limit of our knowledge or imagination. A question that is unanswered does not mean the question is any less valid. If the question is unsuitable, people should endevour to close it for the reason it is unsuitable, rather than just shrugging and picking a random reason.

Comment: @Kilisi I've added an answer to this post.

Comment: Fair enough, reopened. I wasn't using it as a metric for the closure. It was a contributing factor on whether to hammer it open quickly rather than wait for more input.

Answer (score 2):

Just echoing. This post has been reopened.